# Can Lasagna be frozen before cooking, if using uncooked lasagna noodles, not the no boil type

Tags: freezing, lasagna

I have never pre-cooked my lasagna noodles and I use regular noodles, not the no boil type.  Can I freeze this lasagna before cooking or should it be cooked and then frozen.  Also how long can it be frozen and can it be frozen in aluminum pans?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35644/should-homemade-lasagna-be-frozen-cooked-or-uncooked?rq=1

Comment: What is the top layer of your lasagne? (Typically, in USA cheese, while in UK, France: bechamel)

Answer (score 1):

If you only use non-no-boil noodles, I expect that your recipe calls for boiling the lasagna noodles before baking. If this is the case, and if you insist on non-no-boil noodles, I would recommend cooking the noodles *al dente* before preparing and freezing the lasagna, or actually undercooking them and simply adding more sauce. You could also try not cooking them at all and increase the amount of sauce even more.

I would recommend more though to just use no-boil noodles. All the recipes for freezer lasagna I've seen have called for them and in my experience it doesn't work very well to freeze boiled noodles. You can substitute them 1-1 in your recipe, simply skip the boiling step and ensure the top layer is covered in sauce.

You can use disposable or non-disposable pans to freeze them. Lasagna can be kept frozen indefinitely, but many sources recommend anywhere between 1-6 months before there is a significant degradation in taste. In any case, the food is still edible but the quality will degrade over time. When I freeze my lasagna I cover it with a layer of plastic wrap, and cover that with a layer of aluminum foil to help prevent freezer burn. A good layer of shredded cheese on top will also help in that regard.

Comment: There are lasagna recipes that call for standard pasta, but not cooked until baking.  Typically more water is added to sauce as you build the lasagna.  That way the noodles cook during baking.